# Why is python appending to all keys in my dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an Excel file with values as such (-- as delimiter)

```
14:32:01--500--TEST--USER

14:32:24--500--TEST--USER

14:32:31--500--TEST--USER2

14:34:06--200--TEST--USER2

14:34:15--200--TEST--USER2

14:41:25--342--TEST--USER3
```

This goes on for thousands of lines (around 4000), and I want to know how many different users there are per minute. So for the minute of 14:32 there will be 2 different users, and for 14:34 there is only one user (even though it has two entries for that minute, there is only one user there).

So my python program will open the excel as a system argument, and then get all the unique minutes (by ignoring the second part of the timestamp) and then generate a dictionary whose value is an empty dictionary for each unique minute.

I then go back and loop through all the rows and attempt to APPEND each user to that minute key, however when I do so it appends it to ALL keys.. what?

Can someone please point me in the right direction, or explain what's happening? I know my code is horrible and there is a lot of redundancy (i.e. looping over the same thing many times) however I just want it to work

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range
from string import ascii_lowercase
import time
import datetime
import sys, os.path
import re
import math
import string
import json
import csv

minutes = []
unique_min_list = []
unique_min_dict = {}

data_book = load_workbook(filename = sys.argv[1], read_only=False)
data_sheet = data_book['merged']

def uniq(input):
    output = []
    for x in input:
        if x not in output:
            output.append(x)
    return output

def iter_rows(sheet):
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        yield [cell.value for cell in row]

data = list((iter_rows(data_sheet)))

for rows in data:
    date_val = str(rows[0])[:5]
    minutes.append(date_val)

unique_min_list = uniq(minutes)
unique_min_dict = dict.fromkeys(unique_min_list, [])

print(str(unique_min_dict))
print(str(len(unique_min_dict)))

loop_count = 0
for rows in data:
    if loop_count >= 10:
        break
    loop_count += 1
    date_val = str(rows[0])[:5]
    user = str(rows[3])
    print(user)
    if user not in unique_min_dict[date_val]:
        unique_min_dict[date_val].append(user)

    print(str(unique_min_dict))
    time.sleep(5) #for debug purposes


for k, v in unique_min_dict.items():
    unique_min_dict_x[k] = uniq(v)
    unique_min_dict_x[k] = str(len(v))


with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    [f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value)) for key, value in unique_min_dict.items()]
```

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(unique_min_list, [])` <= all your keys point to the same list instance. Looks like [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would be a good idea.

Comment: BTW, your `uniq` (including the data preparation before) could be written as `times = set(time[:5] for rows in data for time in rows[0])`.

Comment: `len(set(list))` is also an option